# In PowerPoint, there are two animations called "faded zoom" and "bounce". How can I apply those same animations to images on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I apply the PowerPoint animation "faded zoom" to an image on my webpage, and the PowerPoint animation "bounce" to a separate image on the same page? The images begin animating at the same time when you first land on the web page. After they finish animating, they will stay still and visible on the webpage.

My guess is I need to use JQuery.

Comment: If you really didn't want to use javascript/jquery you could look up some css3 transitions and animations on http://www.w3schools.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should have everything you are looking for http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/